# Нумерация строк в Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, export

Здравствуйте, занимаюсь в одном рабочем приложении экспортом в Excel, возникла необходимость добавления столбца, в котором указаны номера строк.
Сейчас это делаю через цикл:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= rng.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sheet.Cells[1][i] = i - 1;
                    }
```

Но работает на большом объеме данных весьма медленно, есть ли идеи как это сделать проще?

Comment: Это делается через Excel.Application, насколько я понимаю?

Comment: надеюсь наполняете excel при visiable=false?

Comment: Да, при visiable=false. И да, через Excel.Application

Comment: Для работы с Excel советую использовать OpenXml. Он работает  напрямую с файлами, а не через приложение, что намного стабильнее и быстрее, тем более у вас большой объём данных. Из минусов - нет поддержки формата xls 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте запись массива в диапазон:

```
    var bound= 10000;
    sw.Start();
    Excel.Range r = sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[2, 1], sheet.Cells[bound, 1]];
    var arr = new int[bound, 1];
    for (var i = 1; i <= bound; i++) arr[i - 1,0] = i;
    r.Value = arr;
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    for (var i = 1; i <= bound; i++) sheet.Cells[i,1].Value=i;
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Результаты:
00:00:00.2283636
00:00:36.4328202

Кстати, прекрасно работает и с двумерными массивами, сокращая время вывода таблиц в разы.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек, работает прекрасно и сильно быстрее.

Comment: Вместо "спасибо" стоило бы отметить ответ как решение...