# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel медленно сохраняет

Tags: c#, excel

При сохранении информации из DataTable в Ексель-файл все действия происходят очень медленно. Можно ли как-то ускорить этот процес? Или предложыть другой способ сохранения, нежели

```
 Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
      Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        int max_length = 0, _length = 5;
        try
        {
            if (filePath.Length != 0) filePath_set = true;
            if (filePath_set)
            {
                try
                {
                    excelWorkBook.SaveAs(filePath);
                    excelWorkBook.Close();
                    excelApp.Quit();
                    excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                    Boolean defaultSheetName = true;
                    DataTable[] tables = new DataTable[3] { table_bills, table_houses, table_inhab };

                    excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

                    foreach (DataTable table in tables)
                    {
                        if (defaultSheetName)
                        {
                            excelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                            excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            excelWorkSheet = excelApp.Worksheets.Add();
                            excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;
                        }
                        for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                        {
                            excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                            excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i].EntireColumn.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                        }
                        String data_name;
                        for(int c = 0; c < table.Columns.Count; c++)
                        {
                            max_length = 5;
                            for (int r = 0; r < table.Rows.Count; r++)
                            {
                                if(table.Rows[r].ItemArray[c].ToString().Length > max_length)
                                {
                                    max_length = table.Rows[r].ItemArray[c].ToString().Length;
                                    _length = max_length;
                                }
                                excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, c + 1].EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = max_length;
                                excelWorkSheet.Cells[r + 2, c + 1] = table.Rows[r].ItemArray[c].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        defaultSheetName = false;
                    }
                    excelWorkBook.Save();
                } catch (Exception) { }
        }
        }
        catch (FileLoadException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Шлях не обрано!");
        }
        finally
        {
            excelWorkBook.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если позволяет формат (не нужна совместимость с Office 2003) - используйте [OpenXML Office SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/bb448854.aspx)
2. Загоните данные в массив и заливайте весь диапазон разом, используя excelWorkSheet.Range. Пример тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428053/13996
3. Все действия над страницами проводите при `excelApp.Visible=false` и `excelApp.ScreenUpdating=false`